# Unable to access Fedora VM from physical network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, fedora

I'm running a proxmox host with a virtual network that all of the VMs connect to. I'm also running an opnsense router VM that manages DHCP for the VMs. The WAN port for opnsense is the connection to my physical router, and the LAN is the virtual network.The proxmox host and PC are attached to the a netgear router. I've configured a static route in the netgear router to point packets for the virtual network to the opnsense router. I added a rule in the opnsense router to allow all packets from the WAN net headed to the LAN net.

I can SSH into the VMs in the virtual network from my PC with no problem. I can also hit the web console of the various services in the virtual network from my PC (opnsense, portainer, gitlab, etc.). So I know that opsnsense is not preventing access to the VMs. I'm accessing the VMs by IP address, so it's not a name resolution issue (that's a separate project).

What I can't do is connect from my PC into the Fedora VM that I've got running. I can SSH from the VMs into the Fedora VM with no problem. So I know it's not an issue with the firewall or SSH service on the Fedora VM.

I don't know Fedora well enough to know where all it's logs are stored. I'm used to `/var/log/auth.log` being for SSH details. That file doesn't exist on Fedora though. I don't see any of the typical logs I'd use for diagnostics in the `/var/log` path.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to RDP into the Fedora VM from my windows PC. Before I do that, I want to confirm I've got a good network connection between the two system. Thus testing with SSH where I can check both inside and outside the virtual network.

Comment: I've got a bridged connection that is functioning as the "switch" for the virtual network. It's bound to the LAN port of the opnsense router, and all the VMs pull their IP across that interface.

Comment: I think you shouldn't just assume that it is irrelevant to the firewall on the Fedora VM, since `I can SSH from the VMs into the Fedora VM with no problem` really just proved that it allows traffics from the IP subnet it belongs to. It's not that hard to run `nft list ruleset` (or disable the firewall / flush the ruleset), is it?

Comment: Also FYI (and for @John's), bridge**d** with a d is not the same thing as bridge. The fact that you are using a bridge doesn't mean that you have a "bridged connection". (libvirt's default NAT use a bridge, namely virbr0, as well) What "bridged" means is that the VMs are made to join an existing broadcast domain / LAN by having an interface attached to that enslaved to the bridge they are connected to. (With that said, unlike John, I have no intention to ask you to "just switch to a bridged connection", since AFAICT you know what you want / are doing)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I shutdown the firewalld service, masked and disabled it, then rebooted. I also did `iptables -F` to flush the rules and ensure there was nothing hiding there. Still no connectivity from my PC to the Fedora system.

Comment: @JonathanHeady Probably something is still off on the opnsense then. Maybe tcpdump on the Fedora VM to confirm the ssh traffics is not reaching it at all first. Btw, I don't suppose you have any L2 filtering on the proxmox? (nftables bridge table / ebtables)

Comment: @TomYan It looks like nftables is installed on proxmox, but not enabled. I did a tcpdump on the fedora system while trying to ssh from my desktop PC. The fedora system is seeing the requests come in, and I see response packets being sent, but those are never making it back to my PC. So something on either Fedora or opnsense is not quite configured correctly.

Comment: @JonathanHeady well I suppose you can/should tcpdump on opnsense as well